# How can I replace login portlet in Liferay 7.0?

Tags: liferay-7

First, I'm new to liferay.

I am using the example from [writing-a-custom-login-portlet](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/writing-a-custom-login-portlet). There you can find  [a zip file with the portlet module](https://dev.liferay.com/documents/10184/656312/MyCustomLoginPortlet.zip).

I can successfully deploy it by draging the project in Eclipse to the server instance.

I have even added the portlet from the "add > applications > sample" section to the welcome page (the page that is shown when logging in) and it works as expected: I can log in using the portlet. But I keep having the default login link and modal at the top right corner.

So, the portlet works but hasn't replaced the default login.

I thought that just by deploying the login portlet, I would see it replacing the default login modal, but clearly that is not the case. I feel I'm missing some last steps.

Can I replace the default login modal with my custom login portlet? If so, how can I do this?

**Facts**:

I am using eclise neon 3, liferay-ce-portal-tomcat-7.0-ga4-20170613175008905.zip, jdk 8.

I have a liferay bundle outside eclipse and start it from the servers section.

I have successfully deployed some experimental portlets, including the login example, without issues.

Comment: I tried too but not working.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to 'hide' the Liferay 'Sign In' element with some simple CSS

```
#p_p_id_com_liferay_product_navigation_user_personal_bar_web_portlet_ProductNavigationUserPersonalBarPortlet_ {
    display: none;
}
```